# Ruby: File not found exception, even though it exists, and is passed down by loop

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing Ruby after growing to resent Java with a simple little program that determines how similar a few thousand documents are. I did the same thing in Java junior year of high school for a data structures project, and actually wrote the fastest program the teacher had ever seen (apparently), but somehow I can't transfer that over to Ruby.

I'm trying to create an array of files:

```
array = Dir.foreach("/home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/Large number of documents") do |filename|
    File.new(filename, "r") unless filename.start_with?(".") #Prevents it from returning current and parent directories
end
```

When I run it in the terminal, I get this rather irritating exception:

```
/home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/y_don_it_work.rb:2:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - bmu390.shtml.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/y_don_it_work.rb:2:in `new'
    from /home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/y_don_it_work.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/y_don_it_work.rb:1:in `foreach'
    from /home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/y_don_it_work.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I checked to make sure the document existed. It did. Ran it again a few more times. Same thing with the same document. Naturally, I tried deleting the document. But then it did the same thing for some other document. And when I deleted that document, it managed to find some problem with some other document with *a higher alphabetical precedence* that it seemed to do just fine with the first two times around.

Why can't it find these documents, and if they don't exist, why does the loop pass the filenames down in the first place? What am I doing wrong? Why me?

(Also I'm running Fedora with Cinnamon, if that would have any impact.)

Answer (score 1):

Your working directory is different than the directory your looping through. You could store the path your working with as a string and then concatenate it to the filename you get back from your loop.

```
path = "/home/rj/Documents/Ruby Code/Catching Plaigarists/Large number of documents/"
array = Dir.foreach(path) do |filename|
  File.new((path + filename), "r") unless filename.start_with?(".")
end
```

You'll need the slash at the end of the `path` variable to build the correct path.